# String to jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

## Overview

I am trying to find the jQuery function that matches a selection attribute value and run that function on the selection.

### Example.

```
$('[data-store="' + key + '"]').each(function() {
var $callback = $(this).attr('data-filter');
if($callback != null) {
    var fn = window['$.fn.nl2br()'];
    if(jQuery.isFunction(fn)) {
        $(this).fn();
    }
}
$(this).setValue(value);
});
```

## Problem 1

I'm not sure how to create a jQuery function call from string.

I know I can call the function like this, $(this)'onclick'; however I have no way to check if it exists before trying to call it.

Normally I could do this:
    var strfun = 'onclick';
    var fn = body[strfun];

```
if(typeof fn === 'function') {
    fn();
}
```

This seems to fail:

```
var fn = window['$.fn.nl2br()'];
if(jQuery.isFunction(fn)) {
    $(this).fn();
}
```

**EDIT:**

I seem to be having success doing this:

```
if($callback != null) {
    var fn = $(this)[$callback]();
    if( typeof fn === 'function') {
        $(this)[$callback]();
    }
}
```

## Problem 2

Using jQuery.isFunction() how do you check if a methods exists? can you do this with jQuery.isFunction()?

### Example

Declare function:

```
$.fn.nl2br = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
        $(this).val().replace(/(<br>)|(<br \/>)|(<p>)|(<\/p>)/g, "\r\n");
    });
};
```

Test if function existe, these options fail:

```
jQuery.isFunction($.fn.nl2br); // = false
jQuery.isFunction($.fn['nl2br']()); //false
```

Comment: I know typeof sometimes returns funny results under IE however I it will work fine for jQuery functions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Functions in JavaScript are referenced through their name just like any other variables. If you define `var window.foobar = function() { ... }` you should be able to reference the function through `window.foobar` and `window['foobar']`. By adding `()`, you are executing the function.

In your second example, you should be able to reference the function through `$.fn['nl2br']`:

```
$.fn.nl2br = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
        $(this).val().replace(/(<br>)|(<br \/>)|(<p>)|(<\/p>)/g, "\r\n");
    });
};

console.log(jQuery.isFunction($.fn['nl2br']));
```

See a working example - http://jsfiddle.net/jaredhoyt/hXkZK/1/

Comment: Thanks, I sort of answered my own question after I posted. Funny how that happens. Your answer made my understanding much clearer.

Answer (score 1):

```
var fn = window['$.fn.nl2br']();
```

and

```
jQuery.isFunction($.fn['nl2br']);
```